# Selecting max value of one column, grouping by another is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, group-by

I have a database full of media. For simplicity sake, lets say it has

```
Table: media

id
college_id
title
shares
```

I'm trying to get the articles with the most amount of shares from each college. So, in essence, get the top shared article from Cornell, USC, Syracuse.

I have been using this SQL command, but it doesn't return the most shared article from each college.

```
SELECT *
FROM media
GROUP BY college_id
ORDER BY shares DESC
```

Anyone have any ideas?

The shares column is an integer indicating the number of shares.

Comment: SQL is just a query language, what server/version are you using?

Comment: @Adam: But we have an SQL standard. Ahem.

Comment: I'm sorry @muistooshort, I do not know what you mean.

Comment: Well if it helps I'm running MySQL Server version: 5.0.91-log

Comment: @Adam: We have an SQL standard but generally we put it in the corner and snicker at it when anything more complicated than `select * from sense_of_humor` comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    SELECT top 1 * from media group by college_id order by shares desc
```

That was my first thought... though I'm wondering if I'm missing something since this answer is a lot simpler than Adam's.  If shares is the number of times it's been shared though this sound like what you're looking for.

Edit: I see now. Here's another way...

```
    select m1.id, m1.college_id, m1.title, m1.shares
    from media m1 join
    (
        select college_id, max(shares) max_shares
        from media
        group by college_id

    ) m2 on m1.college_id = m2.college_id and m1.shares = m2.max_shares
```

This will return more than one article per college in cases where there is a tie.  I don't if you want that or not.

Comment: This is pretty similar to what Adam Wenger did... just without the CTE and without the partition.  Shouldn't be anything here that wouldn't work on MySql.

Comment: This worked great!! Appreciate it! Thanks for the help to everyone else as well. Sorry for not specifying this was MySQL upfront (I'll make sure to next time).

Comment: Thanks Adam.  @BrianW Probably better that you didn't or I might not have looked at it :)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that shares column handles the share count query would be,

```
SELECT title, 
       Max(shares) AS max 
FROM   media 
GROUP  BY college_id 
ORDER  BY max DESC
```

But If we assume that shares column is an ID or sth, query would be,

```
SELECT title, 
       COUNT(shares) AS COUNT 
FROM   media 
GROUP  BY college_id 
ORDER  BY COUNT DESC
```

I suggest you to give more details next time.

Comment: These queries will give the total count of all shares of all articles within a college, it will not tell which article had the most shares.

Comment: shares column holds an integer indicating the number of shares. I tried your first query, but added title to it.. and it still shows the wrong title for the result `SELECT MAX(shares),title as max from media group by college_id order by max desc;`

Comment: This `SELECT title,MAX(shares) as max from media group by college_id order by max desc` is what I was trying as well. It just doesn't work. :( It doesn't show the correct title for the row.

Comment: @BrianW Do different ids have same title?

Comment: Nope, all ids have different titles. For example id:1,title:how to get a job,college_id:4

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference if different id's can have the same title (assuming they are not duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the MAX sql keyword

In MSSQL this works just fine

```
SELECT college_id, 
       Max(shares) 
FROM   media 
GROUP  BY college_id
```